# Attr_encrypted order of attributes in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

You can reproduce the issue as follow:

```
git clone -b args_order git://github.com/danpal/attr_encrypted.git
cd attr_encrypted/
rake test

1) Error:
test_should_create_an_account_regardless_of_arguments_order(ActiveRecordTest):
ArgumentError: must specify a :key
```

Here is that test:

```
def test_should_create_an_account_regardless_of_arguments_order
  Account.create!(:key => "secret", :password => "password")
  Account.create!(:password => "password" , :key => "secret")
end
```

the problem is that attributes are set left -> right and :password depends on :key so when :password is before :key, key is nil.

Here is why it depends:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :key
  attr_encrypted :password, :key => Proc.new {|account| account.key}
end
```

so if account.key is not set before :password is set things break.

Right now I am encrypting the value everytime the value of the attribute that is supposed to be encrypted is set:

```
define_method("#{attribute}=") do |value|
  .....
  send("#{encrypted_attribute_name}=", encrypt(attribute, value)) <---HERE GETS ENCRYPTED
  instance_variable_set("@#{attribute}", value)
end
```

I was thinking maybe just encrypt the attribute when saving to the database, but the problem is that there could be many encrypted attributes, and also some people might use the encrypted attribute before 
save. What can I do to prevent this? anyone care to add a pull request ???

Comment: I am encountering this same issue. Did you ever resolve?

Answer (score 2):

I modified my model to deal with this:

attr_encrypted :ssn, :key => Rails.env.test? ? 'ssn_secret' : ENV['SSN_SECRET']